# Create custom plugin for Icinga2

Tags: debian, icinga

I am a beginner in icinga and nagios usage for server management. I setup icinga on a machine and set up all the basics. The next step I tried was to check if certain services were running at ports `8080, 8081 and 8082` or not. I wrote a quick python script for that. I placed that file under `/usr/local/lib/myscript.py`. The next step I did was to create a command under `/etc/nagios-plugins/config/testone.cfg` . My command looks like this

```
define command{
        command_name    check_restarts
        command_line    python /usr/local/lib/myscript.py -w 3 -c 5 -p 8080
        command_line    python /usr/local/lib/myscript.py -w 3 -c 5 -p 8081
        command_line    python /usr/local/lib/myscript.py -w 3 -c 5 -p 8082
        }
```

I then added a service to services.conf under `/etc/icinga2/conf.d/services.conf`. But this leads to an error when I restart icinga which shows up a message `Backend icinga not running` on the UI and errors point to `services.conf` when I try `sudo service icings2 status`.

Can anyone please guid me around these steps?

Answer (score 1):

Don't get confused with `Icinga` and `Icinga2`. They are different tools.
`Icinga2` configuration format is different from `Icinga` and `Nagios`.
So there is a big change in configuring [objects](http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/toc#!/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/object-types#object-types) in `icinga2`.
See the official migration doc: [URL](http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/migration#migration)

So for your case, you need to use [`CheckCommand`](http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/toc#!/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/object-types#objecttype-checkcommand) instead of `command`. Also `service` definition needs to be changed.

All config files are inside `/etc/icinga2` dir and Plugin dir should be defined inside `/etc/icinga2/constants.conf` file.

check `Icinga2` config files for syntax errors before restart/reload with command: `/etc/init.d/icinga2 checkconfig`

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to get some more information is to run this command: `icinga2 daemon -C`.
It does pretty much the same as `/etc/init.d/icinga2 checkconfig` pointed out by 7171u.